# Change keyboard layout settings from a Linux console

Tags: linux, layout, keyboard

I need to change the "Separate layout for each window" from a Linux console.
Could anyone tell me where is the config file with keyboard preferences?
Cannot find this

I need just set/unset "Separate layout for each window" parameter

Advice for any deb-package for squeeze is also would be applicable.

Comment: Do you want to change the keyboard layout or to set/unset the (gnome-specific) "Separate layout for each window" option?

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear. I need just set/unset "Separate layout for each window" parameter

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else finds this:

In Mate Desktop Environment, you can do it like this:

org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.general group-per-window true
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.general group-per-window false